# Django admin, how to hide a specific model field during view and edit

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-admin

I have a django model **A**, this model is registered on the django admin from where the admin user can add/edit data.

```
#models.py
class A(models.Model):
    eth_address = models.CharField( max_length=100)
    private_key = encrypt(max_length=100))
```

Now I want that, once the data is added to db, while editing or viewing, I not want private_key field to be visible on the UI.

I tried using the following snippet in admin :

```
#admin.py
...
 def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    self.exclude = ("private_key", )
    form = super(AAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
    return form
...
```

However, if I open a model in edit view and hit save, it replace private_key to NULL in the db, it meant this value was not passed from the front end which is true, since we excluded the field, however while saving it's value was overridden to NULL, any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Try adding `list_display=['eth_address']` in `admin.py`

Comment: I do not want to display it on list

Answer (score 3):

Based on your question I believe you want 'private_key' only visible when creating object.

You can override get_fields method.If you want 'private_key' to be visible only when creating Object you can do as below.

Remove 'private_key' from list_display if you have one and you want to remove it from list display as well. Add to list_display if you want to show in list view.

```
class AModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['eth_address']

    def get_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        fields = super().get_fields(request, obj)
        if obj:
            fields.remove('private_key')
        return fields


admin.site.register(A, AAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the field hidden, override `change_view` on the ModelAdmin class and exclude the field

```
def change_view(self, request, object_id, extra_context=None):
    self.exclude = ('private_key', )
    return super().change_view(request, object_id, extra_context)
```

If you want to view it readonly on edit you want to override the `get_readonly_fields` function, something like

```
def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
    if obj:
        return ['private_key',]
    else: 
        return []
```

so you check if obj already exists, which makes this an edit, and add private_key to the read-only fields

Comment: This will add that field in exclude instance field and next time it will not appear on the crate view page.

Comment: As @ManojSahu said, this solution will not work properly. This other solution worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54882708/5519739